# jQuery Smooth Scroll Offset

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});
```

This is a scrolling plugin which scrolls down smoothly to internal links in a page. I would like to offset the school by -140px so it does not scroll right to the DIV.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try...

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-140
}, 900, 'swing', function () {
    window.location.hash = target;
});
```

Comment: It should be known that in some cases because html and body are both being selected in this example, that the callback function will trigger twice.